# Can an entity have more than one many-to-many relations?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, entity

I have a table that has two different many-to-many relations to two different tables. Let's say I have `User` <---> `UserRole` <--> `Role` and `User` <--> `UserGroups` <--> `Groups`. Since I am new to hibernate and database mapping I was wondering if having my `User` entity have attributes roles and groups in it, both with `@ManytoMany` annotations is good practice and acceptable?

i.e.:

```
 @Entity(name = "User")
 @Table(name = "USER")
 public class User {

 .... /* Obviously Id would go here and all other attributes */

 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name = "UserRole", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") } )
 private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name = "UserGroup", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID") } )
 private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure; lots of types have multiple many-to-many.

I think *minimizing* many-to-many relationships is a good idea, but it's a natural structure, and is found all over the place.